# Editing attached property in Blend and VS 2010

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend, blend, attached-properties, vs-extensibility

I defined an attached property in silverlight that  I want to use it on Silverlight's TextBox
Is there a way to show this property on the property page in Blend, and VS 2010
Like we do with the attached property Grid.Column, Grid.Row, where we can set them on VS 2010?
and if yes, Can I create its own PropertyValueEditor using Silverlight extensibility?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you can do this in Blend is by creating a Behavior that sets the property and creating a design-time assembly for the behavior.

[Here are articles](http://www.bing.com/search?q=blend+design+time+assembly&form=OSDSRC) on creating a Silverlight Design-time assemblies.

Expression Blend has a file template for Behaviors - start with that and create properties that mirror each of the attached properties - call the setters/getters in those properties.

Comment: thanks a  lot Michael.  Is there an article that shows how to do that?